# printing filtered data getting different result

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I'm new to React.js (using hooks) and want to learn by simply coding, my question is I am fetching data for example from ksngfr.com/something.txt and the data I'm getting from there is in the picture as you can see( in picture i have just put from 1-4, but it is from 1-50). For some reason when i'm for example writing in input '3' it gives me this(first picture).
I have checked from internet and came up with this solution. I want to achieve this: when user writes in input for example number '3' it should go to data and check number 3 (which is 3:95426) and come back with just that result and nothing else, like one box (number 3) and another box its value '95426'. English is not my mother language, sorry for mistakes

[image]

data i'm fetching:

[image]

my code:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const obj = {};
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      let corsAnywhere = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      let something = "http://ksngfr.com/something.txt";
       fetch(corsAnywhere + something)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => {
          const theDataArr = result.replace(/\n/g, " ");
          const f = theDataArr.split(" ");
          setData(f);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  data.forEach((d) => {
    var propertyK = d.split(":")[0];
    var propertyv = d.split(":")[1];
    obj[propertyK] = propertyv;
  });
  const k = Object.keys(obj);

  useEffect(() => {
    const results = k.filter((person) =>
      person.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={searchTerm}
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        {searchResults.map((value, index) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <IndexBox key={index} index={index + 1} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <ValueBox key={index} value={value} />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why do you use `fetch` like this? ```let corsAnywhere = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      let something = "http://ksngfr.com/something.txt";
       fetch(corsAnywhere + something)```

Comment: ```"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "http://ksngfr.com/something.txt"``` is not a valid url to `fetch`

Comment: this 'http://ksngfr.com/something.txt' is not real address i just put it as an example, in this place i have real address but cant put it here

Comment: fetching seems to work but in the code i have some problem in order to get that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if the fetch works then try this code.

```js
function App() {
   const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");

  const fetchData = () => {
let corsAnywhere = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
let something = "ksngfr.com/something.txt";
fetch(corsAnywhere + something)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => {
    const theDataArr = result.replace(/\n/g, " ");
    const f = theDataArr.split(" ");
    setData(f);
  });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
fetchData();
  }, [searchTerm]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
if (data.length) {
  const mappedResult = data.map((d) => {
    var propertyK = d.split(":")[0];
    var propertyv = d.split(":")[1];
    return {
      key: propertyK,
      value: propertyv
    };
  });
  const results = mappedResult.filter((each) => each.key === searchTerm);
  console.log("result is: ", results);
  setSearchResults(results);
}
  }, [data, searchTerm]);

  return (
<div>
  <input
    type="text"
    value={searchTerm}
    placeholder="Search..."
    onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
  />
  <div>
    {searchResults.map(({ key, value }, index) => (
      <div>
        <div>{`value is: ${value} and key is: ${key}`}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i'm getting different result 'value is: 1 and index is: 0
value is: 2 and index is: 1
value is: 3 and index is: 2
value is: 4 and index is: 3'

Comment: Should be getting like this for example: 'index is: 3 and value: is 95426', from that data

Comment: I don't know exactly what the result of `fetch` is so I can help much more

Comment: do you want me to hide the url?

Comment: @walee run the snippet and type 3 in the search input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226386/discussion-between-walee-and-taghi-khavari).

Comment: in the beginning it should print out everything except date and time, and then when user writes in input for example '3' it should bring that with its value and hide everything else, then i will accept your answer

Comment: could you hide the url ? put the original '      let something = "http://ksngfr.com/something.txt";
'

Comment: Sure I can. don't forget to give an upvote to answer if it's helpful.